# how to measure the discriminative power of autoencoder

Tags: unsupervised-learning, autoencoders

The autoencoder is used for encoding features to vectors which are supposed to be more discriminative for classification or clustering. But how to measure the discriminative power of the code. Is there any way to quantify the discriminative power of code?